# Android 4 @font-face display

Tags: android, css, unicode, font-face

Having a very strange issue on **Android 4.x**.
The font I'm using will not display the **European** currency code.

On any *iOS* and *Android 2.x* this works fine:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trade Gothic Bold';
    src: url('../../font/tradegothic-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../font/tradegothic-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../../font/tradegothic-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../../font/tradegothic-bold-webfont.svg#webfontmlgY0et7') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Trade Gothic Bold', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Oddly, the `Trade Gothic Font` appears fine everywhere else on *4.x*, even other currency code's are rendered fine `(dollars, pounds, etc)`.

Anyone ever run into this? I'm forcing a fix by detecting the user agent and switching the font to arial, and it renders fine. PM's don't quite believe me when I tell them it's a font problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where the `Trade Gothic Font` licensed by MyFonts wasn't being picked up at all by **Android 4.0.x** phones on the native browser (as opposed to Chrome for Android).

Once confirmed that the css was right and the `truetype` font file was downloaded by the browser, I tried replacing the `.ttf` file for the same font but from a different provider and it turn out to render the font correctly.

So bear in mind that, at least for this particular font, some binary files might have issues on Android browsers.